# Chess tactics training software

Tags: software

Is there a software/app/website to train chess tactics (forking, pins, deflections, decoys, overloading)?

Please help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are many websites that offer tactical problems. A few allow an unlimited number of tactics without having to pay.

- http://chesstempo.com/
- http://chess.emrald.net/

Comment: Don't forget to add http://lichess.org ! It used to have only mate-in-X problems, but now a lot of the tactics are much better.

Answer (score 6):

Best software I've ever seen for this purpose: CT-Art from Convekta. It's amazing. It's based on Blokh's tactical manuals, gives you positions to solve, and hints when you fail to solve them. And it's cheap (I've seen it new for $20 or so).

Best. Tactics. Software. Evar.

Comment: That software is also available on Android. And costs $7.99.

Comment: I like how some of the problems are noted to have 'counterplay' where both sides have a combination available so whoever's move it is wins.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend lichess, as it's just completely free to do chess tactics whenever you want and everything else.

https://lichess.org/

Answer (score 1):

Garry Kasparov's MasterClass at https://www.masterclass.com/classes/garry-kasparov-teaches-chess has some great examples.

Answer (score 1):

[Chess Hero](http://innokuo.altervista.org/chesshero.html) is a good program with computer analysis, but you have to provide your own pgn file(s).
Any pgn reader will display pgn files, but a chessbase reader allows for special question-based training.